# scheme recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme

I am trying to create a scheme recursive function deep_count that counts the sum of the numbers even if it's nested in sub lists.

```
(define deep_count
  (lambda (xs)
    (cond 
      ((empty? xs) 0)
      ((list? (first xs)) (+ 
                           (deep_count (first xs)) 
                           (deep_count (rest xs))))
      (else (+ 1 (deep_count (rest xs)))))))

(deep_count '(1 2 3 (4 5 6) ((7 8 9) 10 (11 (12 13)))))
```

But I am getting 13 instead of 91.
Whats wrong here?

EDIT: never mind, I know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small mistake at the end. Change this:

```
(+ 1 (deep_count (rest xs)))
```

... For this, and you're all set:

```
(+ (first xs) (deep_count (rest xs)))
```